# InvalidOperationException is coming while executing client application

Tags: web-services, wcf, service, svcutil.exe

I created a wcf service with namespace as ireader and i generated the service reference in client application using svcutil by passing the namespace parameter as Myapp.ireader and the client app is builded successfully but when i executed the code i am getting the below error.
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Myapp.ireader .IireaderService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

**Client Configuration file below**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="ireaderServiceEndpoint" />
                </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:19001/ireaderService/ireaderService.svc"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ireaderServiceEndpoint"
                    contract="Myapp.ireaderService.IireaderService"
                    name="ireaderServiceEndpoint" />
            </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Please post your configuration file for your client.  The error is pretty clear on what the cause is, but we can't tell you more without more information, unless one of the fabled SO crystal balls become available.

Comment: client configuration genrated file is updated in the question @Tim

Comment: Can you brows to http://localhost:19001/ireaderService/ireaderService.svc from the **client** machine?  When the client runs, how are you calling the service?  post the code for that as well, please.

Comment: i can able to browse the service and i also tested the service in wcf test client

Comment: Then the issue is most likely in the code in your client where you make the web service call. Please post it.